# componentWillMount check on undefined before api request will resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-lifecycle

I have a component that triggers some methods that depend on async API  request. I use componentWillmount to check some props. If this prop is `true` I trigger some function otherwise false. But the problem is, that first time the prop is `undefined`, only after some time it will become `false` or `true`. How to check it and wait until request resolved?

```
componentWillMount = () => {
  this.props.init(parseInt(this.props.tagId, 16), this.props.accessToken);
  if (!this.props.notFound && !this.props.person) this.props.onFreeTag();
};
```

Comment: Whats the desired behavior when it's undefined ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function, something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (!nextProps.notFound && !nextProps.person)
        nextProps.onFreeTag()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that first time when the component loads or get called your are passing it some value which is undefined initially and later becomes available. For example lets say you have a parent component as following

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {0}
    }

    render() {
        <Child value={this.state.value} />
    }
}
```

As you can see, initially the state doesn't have a property `value` so the `Child` will receive `undefined` for `this.props.value`. It will only receive not `undefined` when some parent function changes it like this,

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {0}
    }

    onAction() {
        this.setState({value: true})
    }

    render() {
        <Child value={this.state.value} />
    }
}
```

So if on some event parent calls its `OnAction` it will change the state and Child will get `this.props.value` as `true` but as Child will be already rendered `componentWillMount` hook will not get triggered but `componentWillReceiveProps` will. So if you want to use the prop in `componentWillMount` make sure its passed at the first render of the child and if that is not possible use `componentWillReceiveProps` to process the props